# How do I put blocks of PHP code into a PHPDoc DocBlock

Tags: php, documentation, comments, markdown, phpdoc

I'm playing around with PHPDoc and have realised that you can use markdown to add some formatting to a DocBlock. In particular, I notice that you can use back ticks to highlight inline code.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to add blocks of code to a DocBlock, as using 4 spaces doesn't seem to work.

I've tried using `<code>` and `<pre>` too, and whilst those tags do appear in the generated documentation, the code inside them becomes commented out with HTML comments.

For example, this DocBlock:

```
/**
 * This is a test DocBlock
 *
 * <pre>
 *     <?php
 *         echo('hi');
 *     ?>
 * </pre>
 *
 * @return object[] An array of objects.
 */
```

Generates this HTML:

```
<pre>
    <!--?php echo('hi'); ?-->
</pre>
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I add a block of code to my DocBlock?

Comment: Have you tried using `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>`?

Comment: There documentation says that's the correct usage http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.example.pkg.html

Comment: @MikeB Interesting that the link suggests it should work... it's a bit awkward using `&lt;` and `&gt;` all of the time... Surely PHPDoc could/should convert these for me?

Comment: @MarkLocker Odd - I'm also seeing what you're seeing. I'm using PHPDocumentor 2.0.0a3

Comment: In my own usage, I would go with Kasia and not use the PHP opening/closing tags, since the context of the <code> blocks should be clear enough.  Mez's way of having the text equivalent of the tags should also work, avoiding any parser confusion by using the literal tag characters.  Something I have not tried would be using double signs (<<?php and ?>>) to see if they work, analogous to how "<<b>>" can be used to print a literal "<b>" (http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#basics.desc)

Answer (score 36):

phpdocumentor uses the github variant of markdown.

The proper way to add code, is then:

````
/**
 * This is a test DocBlock
 *
 * ```php
 * echo('hi');
 * ```
 *
 * @return ...
 */
````

Answer (score 20):

The phpDocumentor manual says that for **Descriptions**

> you can format your text according to [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), more specifically [Github-flavoured Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/). Using this format it is easy to make your text bold, add inline code examples or easily generate links to other sites. — [Inside DocBlocks](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/docblocks.html)

The [PSR-5 PHPDoc](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md) says for **Descriptions**

> Any application parsing the Description is RECOMMENDED to support the Markdown mark-up language for this field so that it is possible for the author to provide formatting and a clear way of representing code examples. — [Description](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/d69fe63018e3cb01e9d05806bf46a285a440a4d0/proposed/phpdoc.md#52-description)

And that **Tags**

> MUST support Markdown as a formatting language. Due to the nature of Markdown it is legal to start the description of the tag on the same or the subsequent line and interpret it in the same way. — [Tag](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/d69fe63018e3cb01e9d05806bf46a285a440a4d0/proposed/phpdoc.md#53-tags)

## Example of PHPDoc using Github-Flavoured Markdown

````
/**
 * This is a Summary.
 *
 * This is a Description. It may span multiple lines
 * or contain 'code' examples using the _Markdown_ markup
 * language.
 *
 * It's very easy to make some words **bold** and other 
 * words *italic* with Markdown. You can even 
 * [link to Google!](http://google.com).
 *
 * Here's an example of how you can use syntax 
 * highlighting with GitHub Flavored Markdown:
 *
 * ```
 * <?php
 * echo "Hello, world.";
 * ?>
 * ```
 * 
 * You can also simply indent your code by four spaces:
 * 
 *     <?php
 *     echo "Hello, world.";
 *     ?>
 *
 * @see Markdown
 *
 * @param int        $parameter1 A parameter description.
 * @param \Exception $e          Another parameter description.
 *
 * @\Doctrine\Orm\Mapper\Entity()
 *
 * @return string
 */
function test($parameter1, $e)
{
    ...
}
````

Comment: Not that the OP asked about Eclipse, but I'll note that Eclipse-PDT Neon doesn't seem to honour markdown. It's a pity, since markdown is more readable inline than a bunch of HTML tags.

Comment: Very nice that this answer cites the documentation and several examples of the syntax.  I hope this answer gets enough votes to become the top answer.  I was looking for a confirmation like this one back in June 2016.

Comment: Appreciate the examples.  I didn't realize the 4 space indention was *after a space* following the asterisk.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you should be adding the `<?php` tag, I would assume it will strip it off on parsing. Seeing as phpdoc you can probably skip it alltogether.

try

```
 * <code>
 *         echo('hi');
 * </code>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use:-

```
/**
 * This is a test DocBlock
 *
 * <pre>
 *     &lt;?php
 *         echo('hi');
 *     ?&gt;
 * </pre>
 *
 * @return object[] An array of objects.
 */
```

Comment: @JunaidAtari Nop, cause it's <pre>