# Using <code> blocks for Visual Studio tooltips in PHP?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to replicate the results from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55498735/11821074), in PHP in VS Code. However, the <code> tag and anything in it seems to just be ignored. Any advice? Here's my code and the resulting tooltip:

```
 /**
  * This function is a placeholder for a test function. It currently does not have any implementation.
  * <example> Here's an example of how to call it:
  * <code>
  * $this->testFunction( $baba, $booey );
  * </code>
  * Thanks for reading my example
  * </example>
  * @param mixed $args The arguments to be passed to the test function.
  */
    function testFuntion($args){

    }
```

[image: a photo of my cool function]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put blocks of PHP code into a PHPDoc DocBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741302/how-do-i-put-blocks-of-php-code-into-a-phpdoc-docblock)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! My question is basically a duplicate of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741302/how-do-i-put-blocks-of-php-code-into-a-phpdoc-docblock). Turns out VS Code uses PHPDocs syntax for code snippets (which is the github syntax)